# Java seems to be ignoring my toString method

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

Ok, so I have made a toString() method for this Coordinate Class, but when I try to print a Coordinate using system.out.print(), it seems to ignore my method and just use the Object.toString() method, and just returns a memory address.

Here is my code for the toString method:

```
package spacetable;

public class Coordinate {
private int x;
private int y;

public Coordinate(){
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
public Coordinate(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public double distTo(Coordinate xy){
    double run = xy.getX() - this.getX();
    double rise = xy.getY() - this.getX();
    double dist = sqrt(run*run + rise*rise);
    return dist;
}
public double distTo(int x, int y){
    double run = x - this.getX();
    double rise = y - this.getX();
    double dist = sqrt(run*run + rise*rise);
    return dist;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String Strx = Integer.toString(x);
    String Stry = Integer.toString(y);
    String result = "(" Strx + ", " + Stry + ")";
    return result;  
}
```

}

and my code that tries to print:

```
package spacetable;
public class CordinateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Coordinate place = new Coordinate(2,3);
    System.out.println(place);
}
}
```

And the output is:
spacetable.Coordinate@e53108

why is my toString() being ignored?

Comment: Can you give a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem? You've already *nearly* done it, but it's not quite at the stage where we can reproduce the problem easily.

Comment: shouldn't you do place.toString() ?

Comment: You code (with syntax errors fixed and a guess at the `Coordinate` constructor) works fine for me.  You need to show more code for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Sujan No, `toString()` will be called automatically in this case.

Comment: When you print an object the `println` method calls `toString()` for you.

Comment: @SujanShrestha Sustem.out.println calls the toString() method automatically

Comment: Does using `place.toString()` change what is output?

Comment: Are you sure this is your compiled code ?

Comment: Yea, I definitely compiled it. I'm using an IDE (Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, take a look [here](http://ideone.com/Cjmk0b)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{ 
    public static class Coordinate {
       private int x = 3;
       private int y = 5;

       @Override
       public String toString(){
          String Strx = Integer.toString(x);
          String Stry = Integer.toString(y);
          String result = "(" + Strx + ", " + Stry + ")";
          return result;
       }
   }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Coordinate place = new Coordinate();
        System.out.println(place);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that is weird. It runs correctly when I do it on Ideone, but it's still not working for my machine...

Comment: Check the method declaration toString() if u mix capital with small letters the oroiginal one of the object class will be called instead.

Comment: I recreated the entire class in a different package and now it's working... There must have been something odd going on with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you recompiled after you added the toString method. If you are using an IDE, please check that build automatically is  set. If not build the code again

Also, can you paste the import command. just want to make sure you are importing your own Coordinate class and not a class of some third party jar

Comment: I'm using an IDE (Eclipse specifically). I'm not importing the Coordinate class, it's in the same package as the program I'm using it in.

Comment: Also, I did check to make sure Build Automatically was on

Comment: Can you try a clean on the ide and run again. Also , put a breakpoint on the print statement and see which toString method it is invoking

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by trying a clean... but I set up a break point, and as far as I can tell, it is calling the Object toString method.

"Coordinate(Object).toString() line:237 [local variables unavailable]"

is what it says

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public Coordinate(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public String toString()
    {

        String result = "("+ x + ", " + y + ")";
        return result;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Coordinate place = new Coordinate(2,3);
            System.out.println(place);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you fixed his typo.  This code works for me too.  How is this answer constructive?